# Expression as a column and 'no such column' error

Tags: sql

I've got simple query:

```
SELECT ((interest_step / 12) * 365 + (MOD(interest_step, 12) * 30)) AS "days"
FROM "negotiations"."addon" WHERE (days <= 72)
```

But when I execute it, I get an error: column 'days' does not exist.

How can I correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not reference a column alias inside the same select statement that generates it, this gives you two choices:

```
SELECT ((interest_step / 12) * 365 + (MOD(interest_step, 12) * 30)) AS "days"
FROM "negotiations"."addon" 
WHERE (((interest_step / 12) * 365 + (MOD(interest_step, 12) * 30)) <= 72)
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT ((interest_step / 12) * 365 + (MOD(interest_step, 12) * 30)) AS "days"
  FROM "negotiations"."addon" 
) A
WHERE (days <= 72)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
   SELECT
     ((interest_step / 12) * 365 + (MOD(interest_step, 12) * 30)) AS "days" 
   FROM "negotiations"."addon" 
) t
WHERE (days <= 72)
```

Thats because the `WHERE` clause is executed before the `SELECT` clause, therefore it won't see the alias `days`. You should enclose it inside a subquery.